# Using jQuery event delegation on selected elements

Tags: jquery

Here is the situation: I want to use jQuery event delegation only on selected elements.

**The HTML**

```
<div id="result"></div>
<table id="table1">
<tr>
    <td>
        <span class="cell">Item1.0</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="cell">Item1.1</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="cell">Item1.2</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="cell">Item1.3</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <span>Item2.0</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span>Item2.1</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span>Item2.2</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span>Item2.3</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <span class="cell">Item3.0</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="cell">Item3.1</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="cell">Item3.2</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="cell">Item3.3</span>
    </td>
</tr></table>
```

**JS**

```
$("#table1").on("click", "td span.cell", function() {    
result.html($(this).html()); });
```

I need to wire up the click event only on those TDs which have a span with a class of "cell". Which means that the TDs of second row should not have click event bound. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector

```
$("#table1").on("click", "td:has(span.cell)", function() {    
    result.html($(this).html()); 
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Bg2vL/)

Comment: Normally I avoid the jQuery-added selectors, but they're perfectly fine when hooking up delegated `click`s.

Comment: Thanks Arun. Working absolutely fine.